# can we pass bitmap from custom view to activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap, android-custom-view

I want to pass bitmap from custom view to mainactivity instead of using static variable is there any other alternative way to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: bitmap is parcelable

Comment: sorry can you explain me in detail please

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending bitmap, you can do as follows .

1. Convert the image into bytearray and set it using putExtra method.
2. Retrieve the byte arry from custom view class and then decode it into image

But, instead of using above method, i suggest you to,send only the path of the image and load the image using that path from your custom view. Its the convenient   way.